# RabbitMQ HighAvailability

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability

I am new to RabbitMQ. I wanted to know how memory is used in case of HA.
For example, in Kafka the partition use a specific amount of memory if data is present or not in it and so do the replications .In RabbitMQ how are the queues allocated memory ? and How does HA work ?Do the mirrored queues occupy the same amout of memory each replicated node ?

Answer (score 1):

Queues in RabbitMQ don't need a lot of resources per se, but messages will be kept in memory in most of the cases. When a message is sent to the queue that has mirrored queues, this message will be replicated among other nodes defined by the mirroring policy. The idea of mirrored queues is to provide high availability, so if the broker hosting the master queue crashes, a new master queue will be elected among alive mirrored queues. The switch to the new node should happen quite fast, because all messages are ready to be consumed.

**Simple example:**

The cluster consists of 3 nodes:

[image: Initial cluster]

The `test` queue was created on the `node-1.rabbitmq` node and the mirroring policy was applied to replicate messages on all nodes:

[image: Queue with mirrored queues]

Approximately 70k messages were sent to the `test` queue and the screenshot from the RabbitMQ management tool is shown below:

[image]

It is clear that all nodes got messages and they are kept in memory.

Memory consumption of RabbitMQ is a tricky topic and there are many factors which can affect it (type of the queue, the amount of messages in other queues, reaching the defined limits, etc.). In the [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory-use.html) it is stated:

> RabbitMQ can report on its own memory use, to let you see where your system is using memory. Note that all measurements are somewhat approximate, based on values returned by the underlying Erlang virtual machine; however they should still be accurate enough to be useful.